# What is the equivalent of header('Refresh: 2, blah.php') in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I wonder if there is an equivalent code or any function of jquery that should replace the `header('Refresh: 2, blah.php')` in php

I tried `window.location.href = "blah.php"` but doesnt satisfy my needs,..,
I want that after clicking the link it should pause a sometime then redirects,.,.
Is there any way out,.thank you!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you mean to redirect to some page with some pause then, something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.somesite.com/somepage.php';
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are refreshing the current page, use `setTimeout()`:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.assign('blah.php');
    }, 2000);
});
```